# single object accessing two functions in c++

Tags: c++

What is this piece of code doing?

`SNMP_Sequence trapseq = trap.GetPDU().GetVarBindList();`

As far as I know, an object can refer to only one member function at a time.
What is happening here?
`trap.GetPDU().GetVarBindList()`

Answer (score 4):

`trap.GetPDU()` returns an object and `GetVarBindList()` is called on that object.

```
trap.GetPDU().GetVarBindList()
```

is equivalent to:

```
obj.GetVarBindList()
```

where `obj` is an object returned by `trap.GetPDU()`

This is also known as **[Method Chaining](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html#faq-8.4)**.

Comment: Just to be clear, `trap.GetPDU()` might return an object or an reference. and which is further used to call the method `GetVarBindList()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's retrieving the object (or reference) that `GetPDU` returns, and then calling `GetVarBindList` on it.

Equivalent to something like:

```
SomeObject &PDU = trap.GetPDU();
SNMP_Sequence trapseq = PDU.GetVarBindList();
```

Comment: Not necessarily, if `GetPDU` is an rvalue or const reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly legitimate to call a member function upon the result of any expression, including the access to another member, should that expression be of appropriate type.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>> super_jaggy;
// insert stuff here
std::cout << super_jaggy.front().front().front().size(); // legal
```